# Bitwise Operations C on long hex Linux

Tags: c, linux, hex, bit-manipulation

Briefly: Question is related to  bitwise operations on hex - language C ; O.S: linux

I would simply like to do some bitwise operations on a "long" hex string.
I tried the following:

First try:

I cannot use the following because of overflow:

```
long  t1 = 0xabefffcccaadddddffff;
and t2 = 0xdeeefffffccccaaadacd;
```

Second try: Does not work because abcdef are interpreted as string instead of hex

```
char* t1 = "abefffcccaadddddffff";
char* t2 = "deeefffffccccaaadacd";

int len = strlen(t1);

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++ )
    {
        char exor = *(t1 + i) ^ *(t2 + i);
    printf("%x", exor);
}
```

Could someone please let me know how to do this? thx

Comment: How does the first result in an overflow?

Comment: Upon compilation I get: "warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion"

Comment: @DanF, `log_2(t1)` is 79. It overflows a 64 bit unsigned integer by 15 bits.

Comment: The problem in this case is then that the value he is trying to assign to a `long` is too large.  You are correct, I miscounted the number of hex characters and how many bytes that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitwise operations are usually very easily extended to larger numbers.

The best way to do this is to split them up into 4 or 8 byte sequences, and store them as an array of uints. In this case you need at least 80 bits for those particular strings.

For AND it is pretty simple, something like:

```
unsigned int A[3] = { 0xabef, 0xffcccaad, 0xddddffff };
unsigned int B[3] = { 0xdeee, 0xfffffccc, 0xcaaadacd };
unsigned int R[3] = { 0 };

for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
    R[b] = A[b] & B[b];
}
```

A more full example including scanning hex strings and printing them:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned int uint;

void long_Print(int size, const uint a[]) {
    printf("0x");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%x", a[i]);
    }
}

void long_AND(int size, const uint a[], const uint b[], uint r[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        r[i] = a[i] & b[i];
    }
}

// Reads a long hex string and fills an array. Returns the number of elements filled.
int long_Scan(int size, const char* str, uint r[]) {
    int len = strlen(str);
    int ri = size;

    for (const char* here = &str[len]; here != str; here -= 8) {
        if (here < str) {
            char* tmp = (char*)malloc(4);

            tmp[0] = '%';
            tmp[1] = (char)(str - here + '0');
            tmp[2] = 'x';
            tmp[3] = '\0';

            sscanf(str, tmp, &r[ri--]);

            free(tmp);

            break;
        }
        else {
            sscanf(here, "%8x", &r[ri--]);
        }
    }

    for (; ri >= 0; ri--) {
        r[ri] == 0;
    }

    return size - ri;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    uint A[3] = { 0 };
    uint B[3] = { 0 };
    uint R[3] = { 0 };

    long_Scan(3, "abefffcccaadddddffff", A);
    long_Scan(3, "deeefffffccccaaadacd", B);

    long_Print(3, A);
    puts("\nAND");
    long_Print(3, B);
    puts("\n=");

    long_AND(3, A, B, R);
    long_Print(3, R);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do I need to manually split it into byte sequences. Not sure I can split the char string and then cast it as hex to store it an int array, am I right?

Comment: If the upper nybbles of any words other than the first are 0, your `long_Print` will misbehave (leaving out 0s that need to exist).  You probably want `printf("%08x", a[i]);` instead though that will print all leading 0s as well.

Comment: @ChrisDodd, good point. I'll make a few changes now. Shouldn't be too tricky.

Answer (score 0):

You'll certainly need to use a library that can handle arbitrarily long integers. Consider using libgmp: http://gmplib.org/

Answer (score 0):

Before you can do any sort of bitwise operations, you need to be working with integers. `"abeffccc"` is *not* an integer. It is a string. You need to use something like [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/) 
to first convert the string to an integer.

If your values are too big to fit into a 64-bit `long long int` (0xFFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF) then you'll need to use a Big Integer library, or something similar, to support arbitrarily large values. As H2CO3 mentioned, [libgmp](http://gmplib.org/) is an excellent choice for large numbers in C.

Comment: Oh, I could combine what most of you are saying: Split into string of 4 or 8 char string and store in an array (Mat mentioned this above), then use strtol to convert each one to integer then do bitwise operations and no need of library as H2CO3 mentioned. Don't know if it's the best thing or if it would work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `unsigned long` directly, you could try using an array of `unsigned int`. Each `unsigned int` holds 32 bits, or 8 hex digits. You would therefore have to chop-up your constant into chunks of 8 hex digits each:

```
unsigned int t1[3] = { 0xabef , 0xffcccaad , 0xddddffff };
```

Note that for sanity, you should store them in reverse order so that the first entry of `t1` contains the lowest-order bits.